# Find Bernoulli rvs that satisfy concentration bound?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Can anyone come up with an example of identically distributed, but *dependent* Bernoulli random variables $X_1, ..., X_n$, such that
$$
\mathbb{P}(|\mathbb{E}(X_1) - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i| \geq \frac{1}{2}) = 1
$$
?

Here are my thoughts: I tried to think about the case of 1,2,...n variables. I cannot come up with anything for the cases of an odd number of variables. For an even number of variables, I thought of having all even $i$: $X_i = 1 - X_1$ and for all odd $i$: $X_i = X_1$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i = n/2$ and we can choose $\mathbf{E}(X_1)$ accordingly. However, this might be entirely incorrect so definitely looking forward to how you would solve it:)

Comment: Is the trivial example accepted? $X_i \sim \text{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ such that $E[X_1] = 1/2$. Also set $X_1 = X_2 = \ldots = X_n$ almost surely. Then $\Pr\{\bar{X} = 1\} = \Pr\{\bar{X} = 0\} = 1/2$ and thus $|E[X_1] - \bar{X}| = 1/2$ almost surely.

Comment: @BGM "almost surely" - but it should be surely as the equality shows :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems only the trivial case satisfy the condition. Let's restate the example:

Set $\displaystyle X_i \sim \text{Bernoulli}\left(\frac {1} {2} \right), i = 1, 2,\ldots, n$ and $X_1 = X_2 = \ldots = X_n$ almost surely.

i.e. The "joint" pmf is
$$\Pr\{X_1 = X_2 = \ldots = X_n = 0\} = \Pr\{X_1 = X_2 = \ldots = X_n = 1\} = \frac {1} {2}$$

Denote
$$ \bar{X}_n = \frac {1} {n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i $$

In such case
$$ \Pr\{\bar{X}_n = 0\} = \Pr\{\bar{X}_n = 1\} = \frac {1} {2} $$

and thus
$$\left|E[X_1] - \bar{X}_n\right| = \left|\frac {1} {2} - \bar{X}_n\right|
= \frac {1} {2} \text{ almost surely }$$

On the other hand suppose $X_i \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p), i = 1, 2, \ldots, n $ with $p \neq 1/2$.

Note that the event in the condition is
$$\left|E[X_1] - \bar{X}_n\right| \geq \frac {1} {2} 
\iff \bar{X}_n \leq p - \frac {1} {2} \text{ or } 
 \bar{X}_n \geq p + \frac {1} {2}  $$

Further suppose $\displaystyle 0 \leq p < \frac {1} {2}$ which implies $\displaystyle p - \frac {1} {2} < 0$.

As $\displaystyle 0 \leq \bar{X_n} \leq 1$, then the lower range is not attainable and the condition becomes
$$ \bar{X}_n \geq p + \frac {1} {2} \text{ almost surely}$$

But by simple calculation $\displaystyle E\left[\bar{X}_n\right] = E\left[X_1\right] =  p$, which contradict to the condition, since the condition implies

$$ E\left[\bar{X}_n\right] \geq p + \frac {1} {2} > p $$

And similarly for the case $\displaystyle \frac {1} {2} < p \leq 1$. So we conclude that only $\displaystyle p = \frac {1} {2}$ is possible.

Now suppose there exists some support point $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ which is not $(0, 0, \ldots, 0)$ nor $(1, 1, \ldots 1)$, i.e.

$$ \Pr\{X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2, \ldots, X_n = x_n\} > 0$$

And note that such point satisfies
$$ 0 < \frac {1} {n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i < 1 $$

Therefore
$$ \begin{align} &&\Pr\left\{0 < \bar{X}_n < 1\right\} &> 0 \\
\iff && \Pr\left\{-\frac {1} {2} < \frac {1} {2} - \bar{X}_n < \frac {1} {2} \right\} &> 0 \\
\iff && \Pr\left\{\left|\frac {1} {2} - \bar{X}_n\right| < \frac {1} {2} \right\} &> 0 \\
\iff && \Pr\left\{\left|E[X_1] - \bar{X}_n\right| < \frac {1} {2} \right\} &> 0 \\
\iff && \Pr\left\{\left|E[X_1] - \bar{X}_n\right| \geq \frac {1} {2} \right\} &< 1
\end{align} $$

which contradict to the condition again. Therefore we conclude such support point does not exist.

So the trivial case is the only case satisfying the example.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. This is very very appreciated! I see. Then the question seems odd but I learnt something from it + your answer, so that's good :)